# How do you use unicode in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, unicode, encoding, qt4

I would like to use the magnifying glass [(U+1F50E)](http://www.kreativekorp.com/charset/unicode.php?char=1F50E) Unicode symbol in a QLineEdit field.
I figured out how to use 16-bit unicode symbols using QChar however I have no idea how to use a unicode symbol represented by 5 hex digits.

```
QLineEdit edit = new QLineEdit();
edit.setFont(QFont("Segoe UI Symbol"));
edit.setText(????);
```

So far I have tried:

```
edit.setText(QString::fromUtf8("\U0001F50E"));
```

Which gave the compiler warning:

```
warning C4566: character represented by universal-character-name '\UD83DDD0E' cannot be represented in the current code page
```

and showed up as: ??

I also tried:

```
edit.setText(QString("\U0001F50E"));
```

Which gave the compiler warning:

```
warning C4566: character represented by universal-character-name '\UD83DDD0E' cannot be represented in the current code page (1252)
```

And also gave: ??

I tried about everything you could try with QChar. I also tried switching the encoding of my CPP file and copying and pasting the symbol in, which didn't work.

Comment: ^ That's a similar question but the answers really don't help me at all

Comment: Since you're using a string literal, have you tried using the [QStringLiteral macro](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#QStringLiteral)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You already know the answer - specify it as a proper UTF-16 string.

Unicode codepoints above `U+FFFF` are represented in UTF-16 using a **surrogate pair**, which is two 16bit codeunits acting together to represent the full Unicode codepoint value. For `U+1F50E`, the surrogate pair is `U+D83D U+DD0E`.

In Qt, a UTF-16 codeunit is represented as a `QChar`, so you need two `QChar` values, eg:

```
edit.setText(QString::fromWCharArray(L"\xD83D\xDD0E"));
```

or:

```
edit.setText(QString::fromStdWString(L"\xD83D\xDD0E"));
```

Assuming a platform where `sizeof(wchar_t)` is 2 and not 4.

In your example, you tried using `QString::fromUtf8()`, but you gave it an invalid UTF-8 string.  For `U+1F50E`, it should have looked like this instead:

```
edit.setText(QString::fromUtf8("\xF0\x9F\x94\x8E"));
```

You can also use `QString::fromUcs4()` instead:

```
uint cp = 0x1F50E;
edit.setText(QString::fromUcs4(&cp, 1));
```