# printing multiplication sign in c++

Tags: c++, printing

In Qt for setting the label of a button to be the "Multiplication sign" (not astrisk(*)) this is used :

```
Button *myButton = new Button("\303\227");
```

I don't know anything about "\303\227". Also the code below will not print "Multiplication sign" :

```
cout << "\303\227" ;
```

I could not search for it cause I had no "keywords".
I need some keywords and some information about this number and why cannot it be printed with `cout` object.

Also i didn't want to add `Qt` tag for this question cause I think this is not much `Qt` related.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The keywords you want to use is "Unicode" and "UTF-8".

Comment: `cout << "\303\227";` will print a multiplication sign for platforms that support UTF-8, such as Linux or macOS.  Windows doesn't though; rather it supports UTF-16, which would use `wcout << L"\u00D7";`.

Comment: See also: [Unicode Character “×” (U+00D7)](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+00D7)

Comment: Thanks @Eljay and others :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

those are called octal codes for UTF-8 characters, and I believe C++ has no useful native Unicode support. However, you may refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30247319/how-do-you-use-unicode-in-qt)
for how to use unicode in qt.
if you just want the multiplication symbol you may use this “×” U+00D7 or this U+2715 ✕

Comment: *I believe C++ has no useful native Unicode support*  Arguable.  I'm on the side of the fence that concurs, and I'm quite a bit disappointed that out-of-the-box standard C++ library doesn't do a better job — although I do understand *why* that is the case, I'm still not happy about it.  There is 3rd party library support for Unicode like iconv and ICU.